# Access Details View from another controller , when details is being accessed through slug instead of Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have 2 Models Post and Comment

```
    public class Post
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Slug { get; set; }
```

```
 public class Comment
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid PostId { get; set; }
        public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    ....
   }
```

The comments are beings created in the post details page , where I am taking postId as hidden.
The posts are being accessed through slug which is being created during the post create process.

After the post is submitted the user should come back to the post page.
The comment is being created through create() action method in comments controller.
If it is through Id , I can do

```
 return RedirectToAction("Details","Posts" , new { id = postId });
```

**But as slug is being instead of id,  what should I do when using slug to access post details instead of id**. I did try taking slug as hidden in the view
This is the comments create in comments controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("PostId,Body")] Comment comment)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                comment.Created = DateTime.Now;
                comment.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            
                _context.Add(comment);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
               return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                

            }
```

This is the View
Here Post.Id is Hidden

```
 <!--Display Comments related to posts-->

            <div>
                @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <form asp-action="create" asp-controller="comments" method="post">
                        @Html.Hidden("PostId", Model.Post.Id)
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="h4 ">Add Comments</label>
                        
                            <textarea name="body" class="form-control" rows="10"></textarea>
                        </div>
@
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark btnReadMore btn-block btn-sm">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                }
                else
                {
                    <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-outline-dark btnReadMore" asp-area="identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">
                        Login To add comments
                    </a>
                }
            </div>
```

Comment: Read the slug for the post from the database (`_context`) using the ID.

Comment: Would you be able to point me to an article or some documentation ?

Comment: You have to post the whole code including views and actions to get some help. Hard to understand what are you submitting.

Comment: Can you include the code for the endpoint that gets the `Post` in your question?

Answer (score -1):

was able to solve it , by including this in my controller

```
 var nComment = await _context.Comments.Include(p => p.Post).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Now the controller action method looks like this

````
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("PostId,Body, Post")] Comment comment)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
              
             var nComment =  _context.Comments.Include(p => p.Post).FirstOrDefault(p => p.PostId == comment.PostId);
                comment.Created = DateTime.Now;
                comment.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                //author of the comment
                comment.BlogUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
                _context.Add(comment);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                
                return RedirectToAction("Details","Posts" , new { slug = nComment.Post.Slug });

            }```
````

Comment: You're getting a little closer. You are missing two things. First you need to do something to associate the new comment with the associated post (e.g., assign a `PostId` property on the comment). Second, you need to read the post from the database to get the slug. The line you added reads the first comment+post without regard to whether it's the correct post. For that you need to add something like `.Where(p => p.Post.Id == postId)`.

Comment: @JackA Thank you for taking the time to check and explain it.  `Post.id`  is a hidden attribute in the View , which is associating the comment with the post.  I did add `var nComment =  _context.Comments.Include(p => p.Post).FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.PostId == comment.PostId).Result; `
I had to add` .Result`  at the end otherwise it was giving an  error. Task<Comment>' does not contain a definition for 'Post'... if I do.FirstOrDefaultAsync()  and works fine without async()
Would you be able to explain what   `.Result` does? Thanks
I have added the view portion in the question

Comment: The `Result` property allows you to access the task result synchronously, but it is not the preferred method. It is better to write the line as `var nComment =  await _context.Comments.Include(p => p.Post).FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.PostId == comment.PostId);`. The general rule of thumb is that any method that ends with `Async` returns a task, and you should use `await` to get the actual result from the task. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async